# Unable to find Element using selenium(Htmlunitdriver)

Tags: selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\EclipseWorkSpace\\Seleniumdownloads\\chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    // Selenium 3.0 we need to down load Html unit driver.

    // URL : https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver/releases
     WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.freecrm.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Log In')]")).click();
    System.out.println(" Before login" + driver.getTitle());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']"));
    email.sendKeys("test32145@hotmail.com");
    // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys("test2135@hotmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("SWeet$123");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui fluid large blue submit button']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Contacts')]")).click();
    System.out.println(" after login" + driver.getTitle());

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    // read.sleep(millis);
    driver.close();
    

}
```

Comment: Please add more detail to clarify your problem, such as full error message, and which line of code  produces the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.